# Python os.path.abspath unexpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.6

When I start program like this

```
python Script.py
```

abspath return sth like that

```
os.path.abspath("../../house/kitchen") == "/ex1/ex2/house/kitchen"
```

But when i start like this i got

```
python ex3/Script.py 
os.path.abspath("../../house/kitchen") == "/house/kitchen"
```

I think i need to set working place to place where is script but how to do that.

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])))
```

This solved my problem

Comment: Are you saying that on your system the result of `os.path.abspath` does **not** start with a slash? Can you post [a demo **complete** program](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits this behavior? And on what operating system are you running this program?

Comment: this is complete program. And its start with slash i cant copy from virtaul machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When given a relative path argument, abspath starts from your current directory, not the current directory of the script, so if your current directory changes the output changes.